# Calibration/parameter estimation of CEV model

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance, estimation, parameter-estimation

The CEV model for a stock price $S(t)$, interest rate $r$ and variance $\delta$

$dS(t)=rS(t)dt+\delta S(t)^{\gamma}dW(t)$

where the volatility for the stock is given by
$\sigma(t)=\delta S(t)^{\gamma -1}$

Is there any method for calibration/parameter estimation of: $\gamma$ and $\delta$? And what historical data will I need for this purpose?

Note: I will use a stochastic $r$ instead, hence $r(t)$. But that is  another problem.

Comment: Do you want to calibrate the model for option pricing or for something else?

Comment: I will simulate two portfolio strategies. One is the OBPI, consisting of put option + the risky asset (stock). And CPPI, consisting of the risky asset (stock) and zero coupon bond. The SDE describing the stock is CEV. And for the interest rate I will choose for instance CIR-process. Thus, I will need to calibrate/estimate $\delta$ and $\gamma$ in the CEV. So my question is, to do this, what historical data do I need? Is it the stock prices or the call/put prices from the history...? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry, I only know about calibrating models from the point of view of option pricing. It doesn't seem to be your case.

Comment: But that can actually help me :) Because the aim is to describe a "put/call option" with help of the SDE I provided. So I need to determine the $\gamma$ and $ \delta$

Comment: The calibration I know require prices of European call options as a specific date. For example imagine the underlying stock is SPX Index, then you chose a date and as of that date you obtain: - spot price of the index, zero coupon curve, a set of European call option prices on SPX index (different maturities and strike). The maturities and strikes of the options will be chose depending of what you final goal. Usually you want to obtain the parameters of the model to later price a more complex option using Monte Carlo simulation.

Comment: So the maturies and strikes of the option used in the calibration should somehow match the complex option you want to price later. So far I have described the market inputs you need

Comment: After that, you need a formula for the European call option. I don't know if you already have a formula or not. But you can't assume randomly the stock follows CEV process and the interest rate a CIR process. Whatever selection of model you chose, you need to have a formula for the call option. Then you implement that formula in any programming language you want. After that, you have to solve a minimization problem. Something like this: $\min_{P} \sum (C_{market}(K_i,T_i) - C_{model}(K_i,T_i))^2,$ where $P$ is the set of parameters you are trying to determine.

Comment: $C_{market}(K_i,T_i)$ is the market price of the call option with strike $K$ and maturity $T$, $C_{model}(K_i,T_i)$ is the model price of the call option with strike $K$ and maturity $T$. The  model price is obtained using the formula I mentioned before, and $P$ is the set of parameters your trying to determine.

Comment: The minimization problem will give you the parameters that makes the option prices obtained with your model "as close as possible" to the option market prices. We usually obtain parameters this way when later we want to price a more complex option for which we don't have a closed formula.

Comment: By the way, the CEV model is not a common model to price equity options. The Heston model (or any extension of the Heston model) is the one usually used in practice.

Comment: So, If I have a closed formula for the call option originating from the CEV and also the market prices for the CEV model. Can I then decide via the minimisation problem $\gamma$ and $\delta$?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "also the market prices for the CEV model". Market prices are just market prices, they are model independent.

Comment: should say: Also the market prices for the calls* Sorry.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense then.

Comment: When I obtain $\gamma$ and $\delta$ from the calibration method you suggested, I suppose I can use these to plug into the volatility formula for the CEV  I provided, right? Thanks bro.

Comment: Yes, good luck.